# opencv3のcv2.soとffmpeg内のlibavcodec.56.dylibのバージョンが違うことへの対処法

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

opencv3のパイソンバインディングを使っていますが、下記エラーによりcv2をimportできません。

**エラー**

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(./cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.56.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_1/lib/libopencv_videoio.3.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

おそらくopencv3の要求するのは`libavcodec.56.dylib`なのにたいし、上記のパス`/usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/`には`libavcodec.57.dylib`しか存在しないためです。このようなエラーはどのように解決すればいいのでしょうか。

OS: Mac OS X El captan
OpenCVバージョン:3.1.0
ffmpegバージョン:3.0.1
Pythoonバージョン:2.7.10(virtualenv使用)

Comment: .57は.56の下位互換の可能性が高いから、.56から.57にシンボリックリンクを張れば通るかもしれません。ffmpegをHomebrewでインストールしないのはどうしてですか？

Comment: Homebrewでインストールしていますよ

Comment: /usr/local/opt/ffmpegがCellarのsymlinkになっているのに気づきませんでした。すみません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/local/Celler/`にffmpeg2.6.8があったので`brew switch ffmpeg 2.6.8`を使ってそちらを使うようにしたところ動きました。